How to use raspi-gpio to execute a command line action
I apologise in advance as I'm new to Raspberry Pis and Python.
Edit: why Python? Why not shell scripting?...
I'm cobbling together a music player with push button actions. Hardware I'm comfortable with and Linux in general.
But I'm stuck reading gpio pins and sending volume command line instructions.
I want to poll 3 input that are pulled up, for a falling signal and action that by executing an "amixer" command for vol up, vol down or mute/unmute.
I'm playing with raspi-gpio and can read pins. I can send the mixer command manually.
How do I poll and join the input to the action?
I.E.
While [
   If pin 20 = 0 send amixer blah blah
   If pin 21 = 0 send amixer blah blah
   If pin 22 = 0 send amixer blah blah
]

Any help would be much appreciated
Oh and I'm stuck with python2.7 on a rpi B+ 1.2 (long story...)
Addendum:
I should add I've discovered raspi-gpio get 6 |  awk RS=" " -F "=" k="level" $1==k'fprint $2]'
returns a 1 until button activated and then I get a 0 = great so far!
Then I need to action amixer set PCM -- $[$(amixer get PCM|grep -o [0-9]*|sed 's/%//')-10]% or similar based on the appropriate pin falling to 0.

Pls add additional info to your query, don't use comments for that

Welcome.  If you need to use python, you can use this to execute both raspi-gpio and amixer: https://python.readthedocs.io/en/v2.7.2/library/subprocess.html

Thanks that's definitely an option but I'm thinking why can't I do it as a shell script just to poll and some if/then statements?

"why can't I do it as a shell script" you probably could but you haven't said what you tried that doesn't work. NOTE python scripts can be run from the command line (and IMO is much easier than bash scripting).

NOTE raspi-gpio is a debug tool NOT recommended for programming and not supported on current OS. You should learn to use one of the libraries or supported tools for GPIO programming.

find a tutorial that teaches you how to light an LED when a button is pressed ... when your program works correctly, then add volume control code

You haven't specified OS (which is essential for an informed answer) probably OLD if you are using python2.7 which retired in 2020 - so you need to take suggestions to use new tools with a grain of salt.
